# Can't connect to MySQL from python in pipenv

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pipenv

I have problem accessing my mysql db from pipenv (2.7) envirnonment.

Outside the environment I am able to execute

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", port=3306, user="root", passwd="helloworld")
```

and it establishes the connection successfully.
When I try the same in the `pipenv shell` it throws following error:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (255)")
```

Additionally if I execute `mysql -u root -p` insidet the envirnonment shell I can correctly connect to the mysql server (so it is running).

Comment: did you tried: `conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user="root", pass="your_password")` ?

Comment: Hi @Evhz!  Yes I've already tried it out (it is in my snippet).

Comment: **ISSUE SOLVED**  

An important step was to change the autentification in the `mysql` from `mysql.socket` to the `password` one: 
`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

**but also** was to acknowledge that was a problem caused by the requirements.file in the repository: in the global environment I was using `MySQL` with `PyMySQL` version 0.9, while in `pipenv` `PyMySQL` v 0.6.